# How to display C# class documentation in Rider?

Tags: rider, jetbrains-rider

When I write Java in IDEA, I can use Ctrl+Click to enter a class and display full documents of class. I really like this. But in Rider, it's just a little bit documents.

For example, I enter class Integer and see a lot of documents on class, field and method.
[int in idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWF2q.jpg)

In class Int32 with Rider, there are just a few documents.
[int32 in rider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JUyd.jpg)

Now I have to search in Microsoft's website for full documents like Java in IDEA. How can i get documents in Rider like IDEA?

Comment: What do you mean by _full documents of class_? Can you please add a screenshot of how it looks in your Java IDEA? In Rider, you can hover over every type and it will display a part of the docs. Furthermore, you can jump into the online docs.

Comment: @mu88 I update some screeenshots. I know there are online docs in website. But switch frequently between browser and IDE is just not convenient.

Comment: And which Microsoft docu would you like to see for `Int32`? [This one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32)?

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, documentation is available by pressing **F1** when a certain construct is focused in the editor. And one can press **Ctrl+Q** (quick documentation) to show the documentation in a popup. Or set up **Show quick documentation on hover** in **Preferences | Editor | Code Editing**.
Also, currently we show the actual sources as fetched by the source link. Hence, Quick Documentation is fetched from the SDK itself. Thus, there is not much that can be done about it in Rider.